# What are "boundaries" (as defined here) really called and where can I learn more?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, graph-theory, terminology

My guess is that boundaries (perhaps under a different name) in graph theory are probably defined like this:

> **Definition 0.** Let $G$ denote a graph, $A$ denote a subset of $G$. Then a *candidate boundary* for $A$ is a subset $B$ of $G$ such that every walk that begins in $G \setminus A$ and ends in $A$ passes through $B$. We say that $A$ *has a boundary* iff the poset of candidate boundaries of $A$ has a least element, in which case this least element is called the *boundary* of $A$.

Something similar should work in topology:

> **Definition 1.** Let $X$ denote a topological space, $A$ denote a subset of $X$. Then a *candidate boundary* for $A$ is a **closed** subset $B$ of $X$ such that every path that begins in $G \setminus A$ and ends in $A$ passes through $B$. We say that $A$ *has a boundary* iff the poset of candidate boundaries of $A$ has a least element, in which case this least element is called the *boundary* of $A$.

This differs from the usual definition of boundary as $\mathrm{cl}(A) \setminus \mathrm{int}(A)$. I don't know whether or not they always agree.

> **Question.** What are boundaries (as defined here) really called, and where can I learn more?

Comment: Since you are defining your boundary in terms of paths, it won't be hard at all to find counterexamples showing that this is different from $\text{cl}(A) \setminus \text{int}(A)$. For instance, the topologists sine curve which is not path connected but which has a dense connected subset one can take to be $A$.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to define a [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory))?